# how to implement or improve a "killfile" for stack exchange?

Tags: javascript

SE doesn't have any killfile capability to hide posts by trolls and other abusive people.  And, unfortunately, blocking such trolls can't be done with CSS hacks alone (because there's nothing in the CSS which distinguishes a troll from a normal person).  Blocking trolls need to be done by matching their usernames in the actual text of the post or comment, so it requires javascript and a userscript manager like grease/tamper/violent-monkey.

I've come up with the following (based on the same code I've used for other sites to hide advertorial garbage hiding amongst actual articles - no obvious CSS differences, but with identifiable author By-Lines), which mostly works but it doesn't interact perfectly with posts that have lots of comments - it breaks the "Show more comments" link.  Not a huge problem, but I'd rather it didn't do that.

Update: Actually, it breaks the "Show more" link no matter how many comments there are, a bigger problem than I thought.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing it to do that, or how to fix it? Is it the div class for comments `div.comment-text.js-comment-text-and-form` that I'm targeting?

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Killfile Userscript for Stack Exchange
// @namespace    MonkeyScripts
// @version      0.1
// @description  Hide posts by abusive/irritating users
// @author       cas
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// hide posts and comments by particular authors

(function() {
      let Trolls = ['Ned Trollton','Angry Stalker','loser12345'];

      let elements = ['li.comment',
                      'div.answercell.post-layout--right',
                      'div.postcell.post-layout--right'];

      for (let i = 0; i < Trolls.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
              $(elements[j] + ":contains(" + Trolls[i] + ")").hide();
          }
    }
})();
```

Comment: I've got a suspicion that it might be related to a conflict between two different jquery versions.  SE itself loads jquery 1.12.4 from ajax.googleapis.com while my userscript loads jquery 2.1.0 from jquery's site (which is the earliest version that supports the `:contains` and `.hide()` functionality required by the script).  I've found a few methods for avoiding that conflict and will try some of them tomorrow after I've slept.

Comment: Are you sure about needing 2.1.0? The jquery api doc for [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) says it was added in 1.1.4, and for [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) it was there from 1.0.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I vaguely recall looking into it and settling on that particular version, several years back when I first started using userscripts to hide page elements that couldn't be hidden by just adding 'display: none !important;' to specific css classes or data attributes etc.    The userscript does seem to work about the same on SE (but with different bugs) without the @require line, so there was probably some other reason I settled on that version of jquery.